# findstr /X keeps printing lines with no matches

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, nslookup, findstr

I'm using `nslookup` and `findstr` in a simple batch script to check if a website is up.
However findstr keeps printing lines which doesn't contain any matches.
The command goes like this:

```
nslookup goofdedwsgle.com  | findstr /X /C:"Non-existent domain"
```

which results in

```
*** one.one.one.one can't find goofdedwsgle.com: Non-existent domain
```

Which is what I'm looking for. However if I use an existent domain:

```
nslookup google.com 1.1.1.1 | findstr /X /C:"Non-existent domain"
```

I get this which is definitely not a match:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
```

It seems this is from the full nslookup output:

```
Server:  one.one.one.one
Address:  1.1.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2404:6800:4004:80a::200e
          142.250.66.78
```

but why does `findstr` print out that line? `/X` should guarantee `findstr` only print out matches right?
Even weirder, if I make a txt file with that same content as the `nslookup` result, then run `findstr /X /C:"Non-existent domain"` on that, it shows up empty.
What is the issue here?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski
okay this is getting weirder, `nslookup google.com 1.0.0.1 > file.txt` *also* gets me `Non-authoritative answer:`, and the file content *lacks* that line. seems this is a `nslookup` issue and not a `findstr` one...

Comment: @Mizuki you can also `findstr fsdsdfsdfsdfsf` on that and it'll also report that line. Not exactly sure why, but weird for sure. And yes, looks like `nslookup` issue as it also happens with bunch of PowerShell functions or `grep`.

Comment: @Destroy666 ah I see, `stdout` and `stderr` are different things even though they both are printed onto the `cmd` result, and only `stdout` is redirected with `>`.
I see! thank you ^^

Comment: To be clear, this checks only existence of DNS A or AAAA record(s) (or CNAME pointing to same); it doesn't check 'the' website is up or even exists (_lots_ of domain names aren't websites, and some addresses aren't actual machines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nslookup` seems to always output `Non-authoritative answer:` in `stderr` stream which is the issue here. Even though that case [is common](https://serverfault.com/questions/413124/dns-nslookup-what-is-the-meaning-of-the-non-authoritative-answer).

You can redirect `stderr` to `nul` (or `&1` = `stdin` if needed) as a workaround:

```
nslookup google.com 1.1.1.1 2>nul | findstr /X /C:"Name:    google.com"
```

Result:

> Name:    google.com

Or use more modern PowerShell functions which don't have this issue and filtering on them is also easier:

```
Resolve-DnsName -Name google.com -Server 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: aw thank you! yeah I'll try pwsh ^^

Comment: @Destroyer666 and yeah, it seems pwsh is the only way for me. Because both `Non-authoritative answer:` and `Non-existent domain` are on `stderr` so redirecting like that won't work...I can use `busybox sed` to filter only the former out but seems like a lot of work

Comment: update: `nslookup gccggoogle.com 8.8.8.8 2>&1 | findstr /C:"Non-existent domain"` works for some reason...

Comment: It works if you need your other use case of some error output working as it redirects errors to standard output, so that won't get displayed constantly and you can search text in other errors. I'd recommend PowerShell regardless and in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can also redirect `stderr "2"` to `>&` the `stdout "1"` and filter with a simpler `find "string"` command, or `findstr /end "string"`, or even with with a simple `findstr "string"`

Redirect stderr to stdout `2&1`:

```bash
nslookup google.com 1.1.1.1 2>&1 | findstr /e "google.com"
Nome:    google.com

nslookup google.com 1.1.1.1 2>&1 | findstr "google.com"
Nome:    google.com

nslookup google.com 1.1.1.1 2>&1 | find "google.com"
Nome:    google.com
```

---

**Obs.1:** As much as the output is/returns `Name:[some spaces]google.com`, you can also consider that what you see in this "vacant" space are spaces, but it can be a <kbd>**TAB**</kbd>, and rarely some [`non-printable character`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-printing_character_in_word_processors#:%7E:text=Nonprinting%20characters%20or%20formatting%20marks,nonbreaking%20space%2C%20tab%20character%20etc.). so that would explain some behavior when using `/x`, even though stderr messages appear to you.

```bat
Name:TABgoogle.com
Name:SpaceSpaceSpaceSpacegoogle.com
Name: One or More Nonprinting Characters google.com
```

---

**Obs.2:** I'm not saying that `nsloopkup` generates any of these characters, I'm telling you to observe when using `/x` in the output treatment that because they don't "print" something visible, any occurrence of these potential characters can interfere with findstr's behavior when filtering specifically the `/x same character` and/or `/x same_characters_strings`.

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`Findstr /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.